# Удалить каждый третий элемент списка при помощи среза

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать срез списка таким образом, чтобы удалился каждый третий элемент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [17]: l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

In [18]: del l[2::3]

In [19]: l
Out[19]: [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
```